# Double click on listbox item – C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, double-click

I have some items in my listbox, when I double click on one of these items I want the MessageBox to appear with the information of the item I double-clicked. E.g., I click an item "Item 1" and the MessageBox is shown with the "Item 1" text. Here is the solution I have for now, but it returns the index of the item, not the actual item:

```
private void empLbx_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = this.empLbx.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void empLbx_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = this.empLbx.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches) 
    {
       MessageBox.Show(empLbx.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works properly!

Answer (score 0):

`this` is your form there and not the `ListBox`, your listbox is the variable `sender`. so change your code like:

```
int index = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
if(index != -1) 
    MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
```

If no item is selected, or listbox is empty index will be `-1` so `if(index != -1)`  handles both.